# 14-week internship in California: do I need to fill some income tax return form there?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, california, state-income-tax

I live in Massachusetts, USA, as an international student with F1 visa. I did a 14-week internship in California last year from May 26, 2015 to September 4, 2015. Do I need to fill some income tax return form in California?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer, yes.

The relevant information can be found on this [page](https://www.ftb.ca.gov/individuals/fileRtn/Nonresidents-Part-Year-Residents.shtml). Excerpt:

> **Determine your residency status: Residents, nonresidents, and part-year residents**
>
> A part-year resident is any individual who is a California resident
>   for part of the year and a nonresident for part of the year.
>
> **How California taxes residents, nonresidents, and part-year residents**
>
> Part-year residents of California - Taxed on all income received while
>   a resident and only on income from California sources while a
>   nonresident.

---

To register, go on this [page](https://www.ftb.ca.gov/online/calfile/index.asp?WT.mc_id=CalFileMktg_Start):

[image]

And once you are done registering:

[image]

[image]

[image]